# how to add application in xcode 4.2 organizer

Tags: iphone, xcode4

I have developed a sample iphone application in xcode, provisioning profile is added successfully but I am not able to add my application to organizer application tab.

Then before I run the application if I select my device I get an error like

`[BEROR] Copde Sign error: a valid provisioning profile matching the application's Identifier 'Application name' could not be found`

Thanks in  Advance

Comment: developer.apple.com gives extensive and probably the BEST directions on how to code sign

Answer (score 0):

The Provisioning Profile must be identical to your Bundle Identifier